# Can I Copy (Not Branch) a Directory in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I realize this is out of the norm for development but our company is going through a complete split into two. Several of our .Net projects are tailored for both companies; however, we need to clone certain solution files along with their history. I'm not sure if this is possible without actually doing a copy and paste with the working directory and renaming the solution file. The companies will continue to share the same TFS server.

For example: \tfs\SolutionFileOne -> \tfs\SolutionFileOneCompanyA & \tfs\SolutionFileOneCompanyB

Comment: Consider also that branching the code _and never merging_ is a lot like just copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is to clone the Team Project Collection (TPC).  If you have more than just this Team Project (TP) in there, you can clone the TPC then delete the extraneous TP's.

Here's the MSDN docs on how to split a TPC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd936158(v=vs.120).aspx