# Can you copy or clone projects and files in TFS to other directories in the same source tree with history?

Tags: azure-devops

What I need seems to be the reverse of this SO questions: [Can I Copy (Not Branch) a Directory in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938635/can-i-copy-not-branch-a-directory-in-tfs)

Example:  I have a source tree that has 2 solutions but for the next version they want a single solution and they don’t want to use ‘branching’

```
/DefaultCollection/root/solution1
    /project1
    /project2
/DefaultCollection/root/solution2
    /project3
```

Would like to keep the current source where it is for the time being and create copies or clones to get to something like this:

```
/DefaultCollection/root/solution1v2
    /project1
    /project2
    /project3
```

In the process, I don't want to loose the history when we switch over to the new v2 project (though I could handle loosing the future history of the older project structure ... maybe a snapshot instead of a clone?)

To me it seems like creating a branch and just never merging it would make sense but maybe there is a better way?  Has anyone ever done something similar?

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions available. First is the TFS Integration tools, however they do not work well when both source and target are in the same collection. You may need to push the source out and then back in.

The second and more viable solution is to use the Git-Tf tools to clone, with history, your code to a Git Repo. You can then Push back to another TFVC folder with history.

To be honest you should consider moving to three Git Repos as this makes your history very portable.

http://nakedalm.com/migrating-source-code-with-history-to-tfs-2012-with-git-tf/